# How to control visibility of DataGridTextColumn

Tags: silverlight, visibility, datagridtextcolumn

I named two columns like this

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Width="60*" Header="Status" 
 Binding="{Binding F_status}" x:Name="f_status" />

<data:DataGridTextColumn Width="30*" Header="Level" 
 Binding="{Binding F_level}" x:Name="f_level" />
```

and I want to show these two columns dynamically...

when I am coding in CS file like this

```
if ("1".Equals(board_folder_type))
{
  f_status.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  f_level.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
else
{
  f_status.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  f_level.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

it gives me **NullReferenceException...**

please help me :(

ps. forgive me that my English is bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this,

```
Datagrid.Columns[YourColumnIndex].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

If you column "f_status" is the first column of your datagrid, do this way,

```
if ("1".Equals(board_folder_type))
{
  Datagrid.Columns[0].Visibility.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

}
```